# Exit sh script if condition is met

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, exit-status

Maybe this is a rookie question, but I am fairly new to sh scripting and I have to wait about two hours to make sure my logic is right, so I just wanted to ask here.

I have a sh-script which should get the number of lines on a specific file;  the whole sh script should be exit/stopped as soon the condition is met

```bsh
if [wc -l "$file_data" -lt 2000]; then
        echo "does not meet minimum requirements"
        exit -1
```

I don't know if I should go with `exit 0` or `exit 1` or `exit -1`?

Comment: Welcome, use [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for syntax errors, also available as package in most linux distributions.

Comment: Related [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide:](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The logic is correct, but the syntax is not.

```bsh
if [ "$(wc -l <"$file_data")" -lt 2000 ]; then
    echo 'Error error' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

1. The `[` and `]` needs spaces after and before them, respectively.  Spaces are needed because `[` is a separate command, and `]` needs to be the last argument to that command.
2. The output of a command can be substituted into a string with a command substitution, `$(...)`.  In the test above, we use command substitution to calculate the number of lines in the file.  The result is inserted into a string that we compare to the number 2000.    We redirect the data from the file into `wc -l`, which means we don't have to remove the filename from the `wc` output.
3. The exit status should be zero for success or a non-zero integer between 1 and 127 inclusively for failure. Apart from being non-zero, these numbers carry no inherent meaning other than what your code gives to them. Some tools use different numbers to specify different error conditions, see e.g. the manuals of `curl` (the section called "EXIT CODES") and `rsync` (the section called "EXIT VALUES"). Most tools just use `1` to signal failure.
4. Diagnostic messages and errors etc., should be outputted to the standard error stream.  You do that with the redirection `>&2`.  Doing so makes it possible to separate the ordinary output of the script from any diagnostic messages without getting error messages intermingled in the output.  Interactive prompts and questions etc. are also outputted to the standard error stream for the same reason.
5. An `if` statement is ended by `fi`.

See also the https://www.shellcheck.net/ site for a tool that would help you catch the most basic errors.